# WPF rotate Source of Image label when ImageSource need to be string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have my Image label code:

```
                        
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}">                        
    <Image.LayoutTransform>                              
        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}" />
    </Image.LayoutTransform>                             
</Image>
```

Im working on rotate of Image labels. I binded `RotateAngle` in my view model from `<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}" />`.

Everything works fine:

[image]

But how to make `Image` label to stay in same position (like second and third position on my screen) and only `Source` of my `Image` flip (`Source="{Binding ImageSource}`)?

I can do this:

1. Load `ImageSource` as `System.Drawing.Bitmap` (now it is a string)
2. write something like:

   ```
   Bitmap.RotateFlip(rotateFlipType);
   ImageSource = ImageUtilities.BitmapToBitmapSource(Bitmap);
   ```
3. delete `RotateAngle` from xaml and csharp code (not needed now)

And everything will work fine:

[image]

But in my case i waont to `ImageSource` be a string not `Bitmap`. How to rotate `Image Source` only without creating `Bitmap/BitmapImage/BitmapSource` object?

Comment: You either rotate the Image element (by its LayoutTransform or RenderTransform) or you created a rotated bitmap, e.g. by a TransformedBitmap. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to have image label that consume image source as string. Then i want to rotate that source but not whole image label.

Comment: I kniw it is possibile using Bitmap/BitmapSource/BitmapInage etc but when you rotate that objects it consumes a lot of memory. I want to avoid that and im looking for solutions to rotate only image source, not image label as all

Comment: "rotate the source" means a rotated bitmap, i.e. a TransformedBitmap or something similar. What you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: So if i cant achive that in way i want please post your answer again i will mark it as resolve. You can add information that rotating source without Bitmap is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you only want to rotate by multiples of 90°, you may use a TransformedBitmap.

Modify your view model like shown below, and bind to its `RotatedImage` property like

```
<Image Source="{Binding RotatedImage}">
```

View model

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private BitmapSource imageSource;
    private double rotateAngle;

    public BitmapSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return imageSource; }
        set
        {
            imageSource = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ImageSource)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(RotatedImage)));
        }
    }

    public double RotateAngle
    {
        get => rotateAngle;
        set
        {
            rotateAngle = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(RotateAngle)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(RotatedImage)));
        }
    }

    public BitmapSource RotatedImage
    {
        get
        {
            return new TransformedBitmap(
                ImageSource, new RotateTransform(RotateAngle));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution not work, source not rotate in Image. Maybe you forget something or maybe you need more information?

Comment: After copy-pasted your answer image is displayed but not rotating when i want to

Comment: Sorry, didn't test the Binding. See the updated answer please.

Comment: I see you creating something like TransformedBitmap. I can rogate image using Bitmap object but van we rotate source directly on label when image source iż filepath only? My app need to be łów menory usage as possibile. Rotating image by Bitmap is cery memory costly